# Java remove punctuation on a String (also ’ “ ” and all of these) maintaining accents characters

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, punctuation, accent-insensitive

I need to remove punctuation reading on a file, maintaining accents character
I tried this code but don't work how I would.

```
Expectation: input=> ’'qwe..,rty ‘èeéò’“ ”o" "à     output=> qwertyèeéòoà

Effective result: input=> ’'qwe..,rty ‘èeéò’“ ”o" "à   output=>’qwerty ‘èeéò’“ ”o" "à
```

I can't remove  `’“”`  symbols and other of these

Note: `Eclipse` and `filetext.txt` are set to `UTF-8`.

Thank you

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataCounterMain {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("filetext.txt");

    try {
        Scanner filescanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (filescanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = filescanner.nextLine();
            line=line.replaceAll ("\\p{Punct}", "");

            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(file +" FileNotFound");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you want to remove all Unicode punctuation and symbols. Use `line=line.replaceAll("(?U)[\\p{S}\\p{P}]+", "");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `\p{Punct}` only matches US-ASCII punctuation by default, unless you enable Unicode character classes. That means that your code, as written, would only remove these characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

If you want to match everything the Unicode Consortium classified as punctuation, try `\p{IsPunctuation}` instead, which always checks Unicode character properties and matches all the punctiuation in your example (and more!).

To replace whitespace as well as punctuation, like in your example, you would use:

```
             
        line = line.replaceAll("\\p{IsPunctuation}|\\p{IsWhite_Space}", "");
```

Comment: wander! can you please put the modified DataCounterMain class in your answer for more clarity.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I've added an example.